# Change button background on touch

Tags: java, android

i want to change the green background of a button when this is touched without using OnTouchListener. i have this situation: i put some butons in a layer, then the layer in another layer, and the last layer in onother layer. when i touch the button the background is changing(i m using OnTouchListener right now) but if i drag the finger outside of the button and then get it out of the screen the background of the button remains the image from the state when it s touch(otherwise if i click the button and the the finnger off the button it is k the background is changing)

Comment: if u r not using xml show ur code , i will make it clear..

Answer (score 19):

**1.** Prepare 3 images for button states, and put it into `resource/drawable` folder.

**2.** create a new XML file in `res/drawable/` folder, in whatever name you want, in this case, we just give a name as `my_button.xml`. This file defined which button state is belong to which image.

Now, you can refer to this button via this Id : @drawable/my_button.

File : res/drawable/my_button.xml

create xml file using the button image like this with `my_button.xml` in `drawable` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
      android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
</selector>
```

add a normal button, and attach the background image to above “my_button” via

```
android:background:@drawable/my_button
```

Comment: thanks. can u please provide me the code example(i m not using xml in creating my gui)

Comment: @user1021692: he meant,you should use this xml file in your button tag.please see the edit of this answer

Comment: i ve seen the xml is k what is there but i want a code example not an xml example

Comment: is this solved your problem , if yes please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The selector will be as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```