# How do I set a different color for the pressed state of the button?

Tags: android, android-button

I have some `Buttons` on my android app. They have an icon and text. I can set the background color of a `Button` in java code. If the button is clicked I want to display with a different color.  So, how do I set a different color for the pressed state of the `Button`?

```
<Button 
  android:id="@+id/save" 
  android:layout_width="130dip"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:drawableTop="@drawable/save"
  android:text="Save"
  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
  android:textSize="14dip" 
>
```

The `onCreate` method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);
 save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(27,161,226)); }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state/4755934#4755934

Answer (score 77, accepted):

create xml file using the button image like this with mybutton.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" />
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/gold" />
   <item android:drawable="@color/grey" />
</selector>
```

and use this in button xml code

```
android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
```

add those color codes in the resource-->values-->colors.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>   
  <color name="blue">#0066cc</color>
  <color name="gold">#e6b121</color>
  <color name="grey">#cccccc</color>
</resources>
```

Reference : [Change button background on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8132500/964741)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I did not use an image for button. I want to set background color of the button when it pressed

Comment: Thank you very much PolamReddyRajaReddy

Comment: when I try to assgn color to drawable like android:drawable="@color/greencolor" it gives me compilation error error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@color/normalgrey').

Comment: you need to add normalgray color value in values at colors.cml file

Comment: This is the simplest way to do it I've seen, not requiring you to make separate drawables and all that. Thanks! You might add that the `<item android:drawable="@color/redcolor" />` is your default button color, and really you only need `<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/greencolor" />` to act as the clicked state color. The `state_focused` tag is not needed for this. But nice work!

Comment: How can I do it without XML file programmatically in my java class

Comment: still works 12 years later!

Comment: Yes, it works if my app doesn't have a theme. If so, my primary and secondary colours hides the custom button states. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Below is the sample code for color state list used for a button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item
            android:color="#c0c0c0"
            android:state_selected="true"/>
        <item
            android:color="#ffffff"
            android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item
            android:color="#9A9A9A"
            android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

Also please check below link for color state list

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky this is a colour selector, not a drawable - it goes in res/color

Answer (score 4):

Use a [StateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). Below is an example of a selector with a different drawable for the pressed state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_for_pressed_state" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_for_normal_state"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a drawable with selector for pressed states, more commonly done in xml links below.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: This doen't work, code twrows exexception `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #6: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable`

Answer (score 0):

edittext_modified_states.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_textfield_activated_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_textfield_focused_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_textfield_disabled_focused_holo_light"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_textfield_default_holo_light" />
</selector>
```

here:  http://android-holo-colors.com goto this website and select your color and imort into your drawable. goto layout xml and set button background.  android:background="@drawable/edittext_modified_states"

Answer (score -7):

If you want to change button background color then just do as follow..

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       
        if(v.getId() == R.id.btn01) {
                btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                btn1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            }
```

just add this code in onclick event of button.