# ListView items aren't clickable because of setBackgroundResource

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView which is filled by custom adapter. But if I set `setBackgroundResource` in adapter, ListView items are not clickable. There is my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.film_list, parent, false);
    }

    FilmData p = ((FilmData) getItem(position));
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textTime)).setText(p.time);

    return view;
}
```

What is the reason?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the onListItemClick is not called (you can check with a log statement)? It seems like setting the background to this gradient means you loose the clicked state of listitems. Instead, try using a statelist (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Comment: Thank your for the tip to check it using onListitemClick. It was found that ListView items are clickable, but `view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient);` overlaps list item highlighting when pressed. How can I highlight item over the setted background?

Answer (score 0):

first of all setting background resource will not cause it. can you post your full code of adapter and xml file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Better change the background of layout in your xml file

Ex:relativelayout.setbackgroundResource();

Answer (score 0):

The `onListItemClick()` is called, but you lose the click "highlight" because you've set the background to one gradient. To avoid this you need to make a `statelist` (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) to define a background for every state of the button. For example [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147824/how-do-i-set-a-different-color-for-the-pressed-state-of-the-button). You can save this xml in the drawable folder and let the button background reference it:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_button_selector"
```