# Actionbarsherlock - Color of Textselection Buttons

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, textview, android-actionmode

In my TextView I enabled text-selection with android:textIsSelectable.

The problem is, that the appearing actionbar is white and the color of the buttons (copy , select, etc.) is white too. (I use actionbarsherlock 4.4.0)

Is there a possibility to change the color of these items in the styles.xml and if yes: What is the correct way?

---

Edit:
I found out that i can customize the ActionMode Tab using:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/color1</item>
  <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@color/color1</item>
</style>
```

But i am not able to change the color of the buttons

Comment: Are you using a custom action bar? Post your code for it

Comment: hmm it's a little bit complex - what do you like to know?
I am using a customized action bar (actionbarsherlock). I create a Linearlayout and fill it with buttons etc and style it using the styles xml.

Finally i add it with:

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setCustomView(actionbar);

The Actionbar looks pretty good, but the problem is the design of the ActionMode Bar (if i select a text)

Comment: If the buttons you are talking about are your custom buttons, then you should probably add a selector to your button. See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147824/how-do-i-set-a-different-color-for-the-pressed-state-of-the-button

Comment: No, my custom buttons are working fine. The problem is, that i can't change the color of the "Default" Buttons (Copy, select all) what appear after i select a text in the ActionMode Tab.