# Button Press,Text Color

Tags: android, android-text-color

I need to change Button Color(normal/pressed) using  Selector

res/color/test_color_button.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/button_focused"/>
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/button_font"/>
<item android:color="@color/button_font"/>
</selector>
```

in code
class MyButton (its extended from  class Button) and I used following code to set text color

```
 //at Constructor 
 this.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_button));
```

But my problem is ,Button alwas shows default color

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8147889/964741

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `ColorStateList`  object

```
XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.color.test_color_button);
ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.createFromXml(getResources(), parser);
this.setTextColor(colorStateList);
```

Comment: `getColor` returns an `int`, not a `ColorStateList`

Comment: you are welcome. The other answer are correct too, you want to set it in the xml, *not* programmatically

Answer (score 1):

try to set the selector to the background like this:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/button_bg" />
```

Comment: i know that,i want to set style(font,color,background etc) to all buttons,so i created own button programmatically.thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Why changing colors,lets do a complete new attractive thing.... I am sure you will like it

1. **Create an xml file in your drawable folder named as `button_bg.xml` like the following**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />

       <item android:drawable="@drawable/button" />

   </selector>
   ```

where `button_pressed` and `button`  are the images which you want to show on button pressed and normal state of button

2. **Set the background of the button as `button_bg.xml` like the following**

   ```
   <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="250dp"
      android:layout_height="70dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="360dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
      android:background="@drawable/button_bg"  <!--like this-->
      android:text="Login"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:textSize="30dp" />
   ```

and enjoy!

Comment: i want change backgroud on button press ,its works fine