# Android Widget Changing icon

Tags: android, widget

In my widget there is a button, when clicked it takes about 1 second to perform the action, I would like to change the icon of the widget when clicked, so the user will not think its stuck and click again on it, right now i just change the icon like this,

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
        R.drawable.button_default);

views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.red_button, icon);
```

I didnt find any info on how to change the image after it being clicked, can Someone point me to the right direction?

EDIT:
I would like to change in image itself, not the text on the image.
Thanks!

Comment: Refer this [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8147889/3946958)

Comment: This is for a button in Activity, i need to change the widget icon, so this doesnt fit me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically update widget from activity/service/receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455123/programmatically-update-widget-from-activity-service-receiver)

Comment: This article does not show how to change the icon. only text