# How to change the color of a button's icon when the button itself is being held in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-button, android-icons

I had a problem making a button getting darker when it was being held and, after some help, it worked. But it's only the button's background and I think it would look better if the icon inside of it would darken too. Here's an example:

[Not held](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EziNS.png)

[Held](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXJ9C.png)

As you can see the button gets darker, but not the icon inside of it.

Here's the code for the ImageButton, whose `src` indicates the image which is already from Android Studio:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/call_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="248dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/call"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.466" />
```

And the code for the "@drawable/my_button", which ONLY changes the background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/dark_blue"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/dark_blue"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue"/>
</selector>
```

Are the changes made to the icon, because technically the button is the one which is gonna be held, not the icon, meaning that there's probably gonna be a connection between two files like this, where if one is held the other is too (?).

If there's an easier solution like applying a filter to change the color of the entire thing, then that would make it much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your ImageButton

```
app:tint="@color/your_color"
```

Comment: That just made the button become dark, by default. I just want that to happen WHEN I press it. Maybe a color resource file or a method in the main activity? I just haven't found one that works.

Answer (score 0):

> Add this to your button's attributes, it helps to show an overlay background color when item or layout is clicked.

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: It made the background color "camouflage" with my app's gradient background. The background color is already set, but maybe if the icon was conjoined with the button it would work. The problem is that they're two seperate things, as you can see in the code above.

android:background is the color, and the android:src is the image.

I'm considering making it one image.