# Android button background change

Tags: android, button, background

I'm creating an Android app, when a user clicks a button in the app
the button image should change  "to show it has been pressed" then some function is being called

using the following code at the onclick function:

```
{
  btn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sync_active));
  sync();               
}
```

what happens is the sync function is called first then the button image changes !!

Comment: But... You can experiment and see what happens. And if you think something unexpected happens you can ask a more precise question providing your results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All what you need is using **the selectors in Android** like this :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
    android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_red" />
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_orange" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_orange" />
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_black" />
</selector>
```

And in the `onClick()` method ; you need just to call your function `sync()`,

refer this great [tutorial](http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/) it is exactly what you want :)

Answer (score 2):

create xml file using the button image like this with mybutton.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
  android:state_pressed="true" 
  android:drawable="@drawable/greencolorbutton" />
<item 
  android:drawable="@drawable/closebutton" />
</selector>
```

and use this in button xml code

```
android:background:@drawable/mybutton
```

you can check it from this  https://stackoverflow.com/q/8132500/964741

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put sync() function in thread.