# Button always displays with first listed style in state list drawable no matter its state

Tags: android, xml, statelistdrawable

Long time stackoverflow reader, first time with a question. The problem I am having seems silly, but I can't find any information that explains it.

I am new to Android programming and am working on a project with custom button backgrounds. I am using state list drawables for the different buttons that look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/button_pressed_background" android:gravity="center"/>
    android:state_pressed="true"
</item>

<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/button_focused_background" android:gravity="center"/>
    android:state_focused="true"
</item>

 <item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/button_standard_background" android:gravity="center"/>
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_focused="false"
</item>


</selector>
```

In the xml where the buttons are declared, I simply add the line `android:background="@drawable/button_drawable"` where button_drawable.xml is the state list drawable.

Seems simple enough, but in all cases, the buttons display with the background listed in the first `<item>` section of the state list drawable, no matter their state. In fact, in the example above, I could change the first `<item>` section to include `android:state_pressed="false"` instead, and the `button_pressed_background` still displays! It is as if all button states are true and false simultaneously.

I am developing using emulators, but see this behavior both with the AVD emulator and with Android x86 running on Oracle VirtualBox. Any idea why this would occur?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/8132500/964741

Answer (score 0):

Define a selector with the below code and try it as background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/background_sel"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/background_sel"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/background_sel"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/background_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Itz not `android:src`, its `android:drawable`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_new_default" />    
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_new_default_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_new_default" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_new_default" />
```

For more action get the original file from

**drive letter:\android-sdk-windows_new\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable\btn_default.xml**