# Android button states programmatically in Java (not XML)

Tags: android, user-interface

How does one define Android button image for the "state_pressed" 
"android:state_focused" in Java?

For example, how would one accomplish the equivalent in Java for the XML from

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

Comment: check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8132500/964741

Answer (score 14):

Just use addState method of StateListDrawable

```
StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, 
      getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone));
```

You can use constants below for the first parameter of this method

```
android.R.attr.state_accelerated
android.R.attr.state_activated
android.R.attr.state_active
android.R.attr.state_drag_can_accept
android.R.attr.state_drag_hovered
android.R.attr.state_enabled
android.R.attr.state_first
android.R.attr.state_focused
android.R.attr.state_hovered
android.R.attr.state_last
android.R.attr.state_middle
android.R.attr.state_pressed
android.R.attr.state_selected
android.R.attr.state_single
android.R.attr.state_window_focused
```

Comment: I found the following sample exceedingly useful because it also shows how to use 'false' states (with a leading minus symbol) http://heliodorj.blogspot.com/2009/04/androids-statelistdrawable-example.html

Comment: what is the default state?

Comment: default state is as follows:   stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {}, 
  new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)));

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere thanks you so much, I've been searching for setting a state_activated="false" programmatically for hours !

Answer (score 4):

Create an instance of `StateListDrawable` and then assign it with `imagebutton.setImageDrawable(stateDrawable)`.

Answer (score 1):

10x to Tang Ke, I`m using this for different list item color whit selection color.

selected state

```
stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, 
  new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.alpha_blue500)));
```

default state

```
stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {}, 
  new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)));
```

Here you can change color for different state of the row item (ex. paid vs free)

set state to custom layout row item in list adapter

```
holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(stateListDrawable);
```